# What does "<illegal reg q?.?>" in ARM MCU disassembly mean?

Tags: assembly, arm

I am trying to track down a hard fault in a C program and I occasionally notice "<illegal reg qX.Y>" in the disassembly in the Eclipse-based IDE's debugger, where "X" and "Y" are numbers.  (What little assembly I've done in the past was for simpler, 8-bit processors.)

What does this mean?  And is it possible this disassembly is actually pointing to constant C variables there, thus confusing the disassembler?

Comment: Yes, you may be disassembling data.

Comment: the cortex-ms support variable length instructions which is hell on disassemblers, so either you are just in the normal disassemblers dont work arena or you are disassembling data, without any real information we cannot help.  minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @old_timer I'm so inexperienced with this setup, I wouldn't know how to give you a minimum example.  That is, if I'm seeing this "illegal reg" 10kB into the firmware, must I paste 10kB's worth?  Further, wouldn't the C code have to be published, too?

Comment: you can at least cut and paste the few lines if nothing else, no pasting a whole project wont work, nobody will look if you can get it to fit.  cut and paste not pictures.

Comment: and what section those lines came from and possibly what high level code generated it.

Comment: even in .test sections there will be pool data after functions that will both look like undefined instructions as well as possibly messing up the following real code.

Comment: @old_timer Thinking about it again and taking a big step backward, can I mostly assume the compiler knows what it's doing?  That is, since I didn't write any assembly here, it's unlikely those "illegal reg" statements are even legitimate, right?  Thanks for your comments.

Comment: mistakes happen, but in general yes, you can trust the compiler, it is a rare case,  dissasemblers are a problem and debuggers are a problem the create as many problems as they solve.  Of all of the above the compiler is your most reliable and usable tool.